# Determining slope of line relative to a maximum

Tags: numerical-methods, regression

In the following scientific report ([Seismic Q estimation](http://www.freeusp.org/RaceCarWebsite/TechTransfer/Reports/USPNotes/qest/qest.html)), a mathematical procedure of linear curve-fitting is described in words.  The authors state:

> The stratigraphic effects are minimized by identifying the local dominant, or peak, spectral component and measuring the slope relative to that maximum over at least an octave above that component.

What is meant by measuring a slope relative to a maximum?  In signal processing and music, an octave is either half or double the frequency.

Given that the frequency is plotted on the x-axis of the plot (abscissa), and the peak spectral component power is plotted on the y-axis (ordinate), the first step is to find the maximum ordinate value (as the peak spectral component).  But how is the slope of the line $y= mx +b$ determined relative to the maximum?

Comment: Assuming you have decided on the two points you want to draw the line between them as $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ then you set up your equation of line in the following two steps $m={{y_2-y_1}\over{x_2-x_1}}$ then equation of line is $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$.

Comment: Thanks, Maesumi. But what are the two points? Normally, I would think of linear curve-fitting over all of the data points, but what is "measuring the slope relative to the maximum"?

Comment: I tried to read the document in the link, but one needs to be familiar with the subject. My guess was that a base point is chosen to be at a maximum point. Do any of the pictures in the document correspond to the quoted phrase?

Comment: No, there are no pictures in the document that show the procedure, but I think that the peak spectral component power is plotted on the y-axis, and the frequency is on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the most plausible description of the curve-fitting procedure.

1. Find the maximum ordinate value as $y_c$ at abscissa $x_c$.  This is the first point of the vector of points over which to fit the line.
2. All other points that are $x_c\leq x \leq 2x_c$ are used to fit the linear equation of the line.